# Product url problem after updating VirtueMart

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, sef

In my VirtueMart Configuration under the SEO tab, I've checked "**Use full category tree for product links**"
so my products detail page default routing was like this:

```
example.com/cat1/subcat1/subcat2/product1-detail
```

However, after updating to the VirtuemMart 3.2.14, if I choose `product1` to see the product detail page in `/cat1`, the product url would be like this:

```
example.com/cat1/product1-detail
```

If I choose `product1` to see the product detail page in `/cat1/subcat1`, the product url would be like this:

```
example.com/cat1/subcat1/product1-detail
```

Canonical urls have changed too and are like this:

```
example.com/cat1/product1-detail
```

Why has this happened? How can I fix this?

I'm using the last version of Joomla and VM 3.2.14

Answer (score 0):

If you added Joomla item menu links, this is used first.
So if you have a menu with alias **cat1** your products in this category have url example.com/cat1/product1-detail

Comment: no i don't have any menu item. the problem is that canonical url made for the product isn't the full category tree for product.

Comment: Virtuemart get current displayed category to write the URL, so the full link depend the category you are in.
But important is that canonical URL is always same, if this is the case, it's not a real problem.